# Match 'complex' string using regex

Tags: regex

I'm very new to regex, I'm trying to analyse data that come from a simple text file. Before I start the data analysis, I need to make sure the format or structure of the content in the simple text file is correct, then only can continue the process. The content in the file look like this:

```
,file_06,,
x data,y data
-969.0,-42.18187,
-958.0,-39.62946,
-948.0,-37.748737,
-938.0,-35.73368,
-929.0,-33.9873,
-919.0,-32.24092,
-910.0,-30.76321,
-899.0,-29.01683,
-891.0,-27.40478,
-878.0,-26.19575,
-872.0,-24.986712,
-864.0,-23.24033,
-853.0,-22.16563,
```

Looking for help in writing the regex.

I tried to write out some regex, but I keep match the first line only. I can't match the whole content.

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What is the exact problem that you are facing?

Comment: I don know how to match a new line, but i think i just solve my own problem after lot of trial and error

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: While that is an example of the content of this file, **what are the rules** for "correct" content? For instance, does correct content mean "the file line, the data line, then exactly 13 lines with what looks like coordinates where even the 13th and last line have a trailing comma"?

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern :

```
/(,file_[\d]*,,)\n(x data,y data)\n((-?[\d]*.[\d]*,-?[\d]*.[\d]*,?)\n)*(,,)?/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
/(?=-)(.?[^\,]*)/gm
```

Using positive lookahead to start at the '-' then delimiting everything by the ','.

Use

```
/(?=-)(.*)/gm
```

if you want to capture the pairs of data together.

Sample at https://regex101.com/r/a5Dk5Y/1/